# Can not check pdfbox examples

Tags: svn, pdfbox

for these examples:

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/

I tried to check them out:

$ svn co https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/

However, i got this "redirect cycle" problem:

Redirecting to URL 'https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples':
Redirecting to URL 'https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples':

svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples'

How can I check them out successfully?

Comment: try without https. The https is for committers. And the URL is http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

You use invalid URL. The URL leads to ViewVC web interface, but you should specify repository URL that is

`https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/`

http vs https has nothing to do with the error.